# Android AlertDialog style

Tags: android

I'm creating a android AlertDialog but then show it the appearence is:

[MyAlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYzt.png)

but I want the style to be like this:

[AlertDialog Android Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROdKy.png)

My code:

```
private void showAlertDialog(String message) {
    Log.i("LOG", getText(R.string.class_main) + "showAlertDialog()");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(getText(R.string.retorno_comando))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //something here     
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to specify the style you want when you initialize the builder. That style of dialog is an older style known as Holo. I think this is the style you want.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
```